# Inverse of this $6 \times 6$ matrix?

Tags: matrices, inverse

Let $A= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1&0&0&1 \\ 1 & -1&1&-1&0&1\\ 1&-1&-1&0&-1&1\\ 1&-1&0&1&1&0\\ 1&1&0&-1&1& -1\\ 1&1&-1&1&-1&0 \end{pmatrix} $.

Then the inverse given in the paper I have is $A^{-1}=\frac16\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1&1&1&1 \\ 1 & -1&-1&-1&1&1\\ 2&2&-2&0&-2&0\\ 0&0&-2&2&-2&2\\ 0&-2&0&2&2& -2\\ 2&-2&2&0&0&-2 \end{pmatrix}$

but when I find it by online calculator [here](http://matrix.reshish.com/inverse.php), I get $A^{-1}=$ [image]

Shouldn't they be same as matrix inverse is unique?

Comment: Try multiplying them and see? And yes matrix inverse is unique

Answer (score 1):

Your inverse is wrong, if you calculate $A^{-1}\cdot A$ with your inverse the value of the upper right number will be $\frac{1}{2}$ and not zero.

Comment: Yes. Means online calculator is wrong but its steps are all right.. Where is the mistake. see http://matrix.reshish.com/inverCalculation.php

Comment: @Departed no I guess the online calculator is right, I used your calculated matrix

Comment: so sorry. I did a typo in (6,6,)th entry. please see now.  Mmy $A^{-1}$ must be correct

Comment: @Departed my calculations only used the first row of your inverse, so my arguement is still valid

Comment: ohh sorry I have typo in matrix too.

Comment: @Departed the (2,6) entry does a different value there

Comment: yes now it should calculate same inverse. Thanks